# Post hooks on mongoose subdocuments

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

How do I setup a post hook on subdocuments in mongoose?

I have a schema A, that is embedded as a subdocument in multiple other schemas B, C, D etc. These are actual subdocuments and not references.

Whenever I fire a find on any of B, C, D I want to modify certain fields in A before I return the entire document corresponding to schema B or C or D.

I tried to setup post-find, post-findOne and even post-init hooks on the schema A but none of them got triggered when I did a findOne on schema B.

Is there a way to do this on mongoose?

Comment: Wait if you want to act on `find` it seems to me your post hooks should be on B, C, D etc schemas. Since your A schema is just an embedded doc then on find B etc do your thing not on post find A no?

Comment: Yes, that will work but will be very cumbersome because there are multiple arrays containing type a embedded in b c and d. So parsing each out to modify will be a pain. Also it will be repetitive, since I now need to write a separate hook on each of b c d and potentially every single schema that includes A in the future.